# Ship to all countries selection not disabling to select specific countries in Shipping methods

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

Admin end shipping methods countries selection not disabling when I choose to allow all countries.

[image]

Please help me. Urgent task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have selected wrong selection.

First Select "ship to specific countries" from ship to Applicable countries.
Then select a specific country from drop down. In case "India" just select India so that, other countries will be disabled.

Comment: I have already tried this too. But the same issue happens.

Comment: Is this payment method or product restriction?

Comment: This is from shipping methods.